# How to stop angular-cli freezing on "loadRequestedDeps: silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree"?

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I am running Windows 8.1 with node version 7.7.3 and npm version 4.1.2.

I have been working on an Angular tutorial without issues. At some point since finishing that tutorial I installed Python. I am not sure if it is related, but I have mentioned it just in case.

Today I am trying to create an Angular application and it hung without completing.

I did some research and it tells me to do this:

```
npm uninstall -g @angluar/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

The last command hangs at this point:

```
loadRequestedDeps: silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
```

I opened the command prompt "run as administrator" to run these commands.

Everything I try fails. I have connected to a completely different network to eliminate that as the problem and that didn't fix anything. I have uninstalled and reinstalled node.js and that hasn't fixed the problem either.

I can `ping registry.npmjs.org` just fine.

What is causing this error?

Comment: Can you try to install using node.js command prompt. I have ran into issues with windows command prompt even when running as administrator.

Comment: I tried that and get the same issue. I have also noted that anything I attempt to install using npm stalls at the exact same spot. I am thinking this is some type of npm issue.

Comment: can you install Jquery? npm install -g jquery

Comment: Nope. Hangs in the exact same spot.

Comment: I even did a complete uninstall of node and reinstalled it. No luck. It hangs in the exact same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer! I ran the following command in the command window:

```
echo %temp%
```

It had 3 temp paths in there. I removed the two I didn't need and voila, it works!